# run node.js on homegroup

Tags: node.js, networking

Am I expecting something from node.js that it can't give? I have Windows7 homegroup network set up and I have node.js running on one computer and providing a simple server.js script to localhost:3000 This runs fine on the computer node.js  is running on but won't show up in browser of other computers on the network. Is it a network permission problem or does node.js have to be on all the computers? I have give node.js permission to connect to home network and public networks in the firewall section of Windows7 security. Chrome responds with localhost refused to connect.Researched here

```
http://wesbos.com/localhost-mobile-device-testing/
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/network-connection-issue-localhost-refused/65d21852-ce43-4fa8-a85b-04256f80c81f
```

I have becoming less confused by the help I've got from the comments.

Edit: I have learned a lot from the comments and followed the leads mentioned:
@barry-johnson: you would not need node on the other machines.
localhost is whatever computer you are on, so the other machine is, in that case, looking for a server on the local machine. You would want to reference it by the name of the machine (if your local network will support it) or just with the server machine's IP address.
If access by the IP address doesn't work, then you do probably have a firewall setting blocking access to the PC running node. You might just need to change your Windows firewall settings. –
Pull up a cmd console and type ipconfig

```
http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/515977-how-configure-windows-firewall-windows-7-a.html
```

Also found

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4517-virtual-private-network-vpn-enable-incoming-vpn-connections.html
```

I will continue to tweek these settings and suggestions and see what comes of it. The problem now seem a network problem and not node.js related.

Comment: This is not a node issue. How are you trying to access it from the other machines on the network? By IP address or by the hostname? And yes, you may have firewall issues as well. But no, you would not need node on the other machines.

Comment: @barry-johnson I type in localhost:3000 same as on source computer. Good to know I don't need node.js on the other computers.

Comment: `localhost` is whatever computer you are on, so the other machine is, in that case, looking for a server on the local machine. You would want to reference it by the name of the machine (if your local network will support it) or just with the server machine's IP address.

Comment: @barry-johnson I am beginning to understand. I put in the name of the other computer like this victor-pc:3000 but it timed out so I will look into ip addressing.

Comment: If access by the IP address doesn't work, then you do probably have a firewall setting blocking access to the PC running node. You might just need to change your Windows firewall settings.

Comment: @barry-johnson before I go searching beyond. The Internet ip address are the same for all the computers on the system so I tried 192.168.1.1 and a few other derivatives of this. Nothing. Do you know how to find the ip of my computer on a network.

Comment: Pull up a cmd console and type `ipconfig`

Comment: Got 1 machine as 192.168.1.100 and the other as 101 but the 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.100:3000 timed out. I best research it and come back if I can't connect. Many thanks.

Comment: I had run out to breakfast. From what you describe, (assuming 192.168.1.100 is the address of the machine running node), you do have some setting or other blocking it, either a routing issue or (much more likely) some sort of firewall on Windows. I don't have a Windows 7 instance running here, but [this post](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/515977-how-configure-windows-firewall-windows-7-a.html) has a decent setup guide with screenshots, which may be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Question Edited.